# When exporting an (animated) GIF, is it possible to specify the size of the color palette?

Tags: export, animation, image

I've exported an animation to animated GIF, which generated a 15mb file.  I've been asked if I could regenerate the file, limiting it to only 16 colors, but I can't find any documentation on how I might do that.  Is there a way to make `Export[]` reduce the color palette, preferably dithering as needed?

Comment: `Export[]` in old versions of *Mathematica* supported a `"ColorReductionPalette"` option for exporting GIFs; it seems they have either removed or hidden this functionality. As for dithering, it seems Floyd-Steinberg dithering is already performed by default when exporting GIFs.

Comment: You can always post-process your image using [gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) or [Nconvert](http://www.xnview.com/en/nconvert.html) or http://www.optiview.com/. All of which are cross platform alternatives. Since the first two are command-line tools, you can also automate that process from MMA if necessary.

Comment: You could try something like `Export["image.gif", ColorQuantize[#, 16] & /@ imglist]`.

Comment: @Heike Nice! I posted an answer (b/c it is too long for a comment) with the results

Comment: Using gifsicle as @Ajasja suggested, one can get roughly 30% smaller files while keeping all 256 colors. The command that I used to test this is `gifsicle --colors=256 --optimize=2 < in.gif > out.gif`

Comment: @jens great tip; `gifsicle --optimize=3 --colors=16 < enormous.gif > smaller.gif` produces a file *half* the size of the original 15 megabyte animated GIF file in question. The source animation uses very few colors anyway so 16 colors seems sufficient to my eye...

Answer (score 4):

Just too long for a comment. Here you can see the savings obtained by using the method explained in Heike's comment above:

```
i := ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {100, 200}], ColorFunction -> Hue];
StringLength@ExportString[k = {i, i}, "GIF"]
StringLength@ExportString[ColorQuantize[#, 16] & /@ k, "GIF"]
(*
114000 
57095
*)
```

Comment: Here's how to verify that only sixteen colors were used: `ExportString[ColorQuantize[test, 16], "GIF"]; Length[ImportString[%, "ColorMap"]]`

Comment: @J.M. Not sure, but perhaps one should check the `"GlobalColorMap"` too