# How to set BitDepth and control dithering on exported GIF

Tags: export, image-processing, image, animation

Related: [How to export a Graphics to PNG with BitDepth greater than 8?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67235/how-to-export-a-graphics-to-png-with-bitdepth-greater-than-8)

I can't find a way to set the BitDepth of an exported GIF. It doesn't need to have great colour data, but I don't want to reduce the resolution. It's going in a powerpoint slide, so I'm trying to reduce its size. With a list of images called `imgList`, here's what I try:

```
Export["anim.gif",imgList,"BitDepth"->5, "DisplayDurations"->0.04];
```

However, no matter what I do, this always exports with a `BitDepth` of `8`. I check this like so:

```
Import["anim.gif","BitDepth"]
```

Minimum working example:

```
imgList = Table[Graphics@Circle[],{i,1,50}];
Export["anim.gif",imgList,"BitDepth"->5, "DisplayDurations"->0.04];
Import["anim.gif","BitDepth"]

Output: 8
```

---

Investigating nikie's comment, it appears as though the GIF standard uses a 256-colour palette, and I'm not sure this can be changed. However, I did find this partial solution:

[When exporting an (animated) GIF, is it possible to specify the size of the color palette?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6561/when-exporting-an-animated-gif-is-it-possible-to-specify-the-size-of-the-colo?rq=1)

Although it doesn't change the actual bit depth of the GIF (I guess this isn't possible as 8 bits is built into the standard?), it does compress the colours of the source images so that they only pull from a limited colour palette. I exported the GIF using this:

```
imgList = Table[Graphics@Circle[],{i,1,50}];
Export["anim.gif",ColorQuantize[#,2^5]&/@imgList,"DisplayDurations"->0.04];
Import["anim.gif","BitDepth"]

Output: 8
```

Here, `2^5` indicates that each image should be compressed to pull from a palette of `2^5` colours which corresponds to a bit depth of `5`. Although the bit depth of the exported GIF is still `8`, the file size is reduced. I guess this is due to smart compression within the GIF standard.

But there's a problem. The colouring of the GIF is unacceptably choppy, even when quantising to `8` bits. There are parts of the image that never change colour, but the GIF renders them as flashing quickly from grey to red. Here's an example still from an `8`-bit export using this method:

[image]

---

## Update

Here are comparisons of the output when the images **are** `ColorQuantize[#,2^8]`-ed...

[image]

...and are not:
[image]

Both of these methods quantise the colours to `8`-bits, and both use dithering. Yet one of them is higher quality than the other (i.e. doesn't produce the weird greyness as illustrated above nearly as badly). I want this superior output, at a lower bit depth. How can I achieve this?

Using `ColorQuantize` with no dithering as nikie suggests does fix the grey artefact problem, but makes the image on the right look much worse:

[image]

Is there perhaps a way to fine-tune the dithering to resolve this?

Comment: I think the GIF format only supports up to 8 bits per pixel. At least that's what it says on Wikipedia

Comment: @nikie - Good thing I'm aiming for less than 8 then.

Comment: Sounds like the dithering messes up your animation. Did you try turning dithering off? i.e. Using `ColorQuantize[#,2^5,Dithering -> False]`

Comment: @nikie - Nice suggestion! I switched OSs and won't be able to try this for a while. I suspect it will solve the problem, but unfortunately there's another half of the image (I've only shown the left half) for which dithering is desired. I think I'll have to find a way to break the image apart, quantize each half with dithering on/off, stitch them back together, and create a GIF. Might be too much trouble.

Comment: @nikie - Please see my update if you have anything you can add.